# JQuery onClick not responding to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to achieve a simple code with jquery since i'm leanring, but i'm having some trouble with a button not sending an event or/and the jquery are not handling it. 
This is my code :

```
<button id="btn_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_delete').on('click', function(){
        alert();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure ? ", fucntion(answer){
            alert('User has pressed ' + answer);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to use this [BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com/), so if someone can help me or does see an error in my programming, please answer me, thanks you !

**Console Output:**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getColumnNumber is not defined ListArticles:562 Uncaught ReferenceError: getColumnNumber is not defined ListArticles:642 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: So you don't get the alert? Do you have more then one element that uses the ID `btn_delete`?

Comment: I didn't even know about the console, thanks. Here is the output Uncaught ReferenceError: getColumnNumber is not defined ListArticles:562
Uncaught ReferenceError: getColumnNumber is not defined ListArticles:642
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {..
@j08691 Yes, i don't get the alert, i have only one element using this id

Comment: You're getting an error that's unrelated to the example you posted. Try narrowing the problem down a bit.

Comment: First, take bootbox out of the function. Change the alert to a console.log('something got clicked'); Then test this while watching your browser's console. If all is good add the bootbox back in and try again.

Comment: I don't really think the error is within the code pasted at all, probably blowing up when sending server variables somewhere upstream on the page. Anyways, fucntion is a typo in your bootbox callback, should be function

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried the console.log and it showing the right message ont the console, but when switching back to bootbox, nothing happens. I verfiyed it, the bootbox script is well imported

Comment: @BryanMoyles you're right, now that i fixed the typo, i'm getting this error on the console : Uncaught ReferenceError: bootbox is not defined . I think bootbox is not imported, i don't now why, when put an alert on the bootbox.js file i'm getting it ...

Comment: That was all my fault, the script wasn't correctly loaded, i'm importing it by the web and it's working. Anyway thanks all of you for helping me !

Comment: @R00t You must mark an answer if it exists or you must post your own answer, which might help someone else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3tQ5/)***</kbd>

***jQuery Code***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_delete').on('click', function () {
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure ? ", function(answer) {
            alert('User has pressed ' + answer);
        });
    });
});
```

---

Adding more to @Richer's answer even `alert();` throws an error `NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.alert]`...
Alert must have one argument.. Blank alert can be done using this code `alert('');`

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 3):

I notice a typo in the word 'function' here

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure ? ", fucntion(answer){
```

Once fixed, the event work : http://jsfiddle.net/M3tQ5/ - thanks to Bhavik

You should use your browser console (firefox or chrome is prefered), it's great help when is time to debug javascript code.
You can open with pressing F12.

Hope that fix your issue.

Comment: NO doubt you are correct but the fiddle link you gave is not working... You must correct it...

Comment: Thank you, even if @JayBlanchard already told me this in the comment

Comment: @Bhavik I updated my answer with your Fiddle link. 
Thanks, I didn't know you can point to external ressource with Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake while writing function in `bootbox.confirm("Are you sure ? ", fucntion(answer){` it should be `bootbox.confirm("Are you sure ? ", function(answer){`.
And little modification in your code ,
Your button

```
<button id="btn_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
```

Javascript code ,

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btn_delete", function(e) {
       bootbox.confirm("Are you sure ? ", function(answer){
             alert('User has pressed ' + answer);
      });
 });
```

And i hope you have loaded required js and bootstrap js also.